# ROS2: colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install PermissionError WinError5

Tags: ros2, colcon

I am experiencing problems with colcon build. I am running it in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 as admin. I get this error for every colcon build i was trying to create.

I am using ROS2 foxy for Windows.
View the full Error Message below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\setup.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional>cd \dev\ros2_ws

C:\dev\ros2_ws>colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install

[0.790s] root DEBUG Using proactor: IocpProactor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
[0.804s] colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin WARNING The path 'C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows' in the environment variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_executors
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client [0.80s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server [0.73s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client [0.67s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [0.61s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher [0.58s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_service [0.51s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber [0.47s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer [0.39s, exited with code 1]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\executor\__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_ros\task\ament_cmake\build.py", line 59, in build
    rc = await extension.build(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 87, in build
    rc = await self._reconfigure(args, env)
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_cmake\task\cmake\build.py", line 174, in _reconfigure
    completed = await run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\task\__init__.py", line 177, in run
    completed = await colcon_core_subprocess_run(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 81, in run
    rc, _, _ = await _async_check_call(
  File "c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\subprocess.py", line 139, in _async_check_call
    process = await create_subprocess(
  File "asyncio\subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 385, in _make_subprocess_transport
  File "asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
  File "asyncio\windows_events.py", line 881, in _start
  File "asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor [0.33s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclpy_executors [1.16s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server [1.00s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client [1.08s]

 

Summary: 0 packages finished [2.03s]
  9 packages failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
  3 packages aborted: examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server
  9 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
  4 packages not processed
[WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
```

Does someone has any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was somehow fixed and was related to Cmake:
https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/448#issuecomment-1766756522

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `--symlink_install`

Symbolic links are supported in a limited way on Windows but as far as I know you have to enable developer mode to use it without administrative privilege escalation:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

More here:

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/356#issuecomment-306889961

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is not connected  to --symlink_install. I have the same issue running any colcon command even without --symlink_install. 
I still tried to enable the "for developer" features, but this did not change or fix anythink.
Thank you for your idea though :)

Comment: I wonder if you actually have a directory permissions error, I would double-check for read-only folders and similar issues. I don't see why your workspace would have this issue, though. My next step here would probably be to add some temporary debug printing in colcon_core\subprocess.py to see what it's trying to do that is getting denied. You may also get some more info from colcon with `--event-handlers console_direct+` or `--event-handlers console_cohesion+`

Comment: I think the subprocess tries to call a command with the following args: ['"C:\\dev\\ros2_ws\\build\\turtlesim\\colcon_command_prefix_build.bat" && set']
I don't see a problem with that, but maybe you do. I thought of maybe trying to start some different subprocesses using python to narrow down the cause.

Comment: This was somehow fixed here:
https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/448#issuecomment-1766756522